# Wrong result in a project euler 31

Tags: c++, c

I tried to solve [project euler 31](http://projecteuler.net/problem=31):

> In England the currency is made up of pound, £, and pence, p, and
>   there are eight coins in general circulation:
>
> 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1 (100p) and £2 (200p). It is possible to
>   make £2 in the following way:
>
> 1×£1 + 1×50p + 2×20p + 1×5p + 1×2p + 3×1p
>
> How many different ways can £2 be
>   made using any number of coins?

with this code:

```
#define to2(x) ((x)/2+1)

int to5(x)
{
    int acc=1;
    for(;x>0;x-=5)
        acc+=to2(x);
    return acc;
}

int to10(x)
{
    int acc=1;
    for(;x>0;x-=10)
        acc+=to5(x);
    return acc;
}

int to20(x)
{
    int acc=1;
    for(;x>0;x-=20)
        acc+=to10(x);
    return acc;
}

int to50(x)
{
    int acc=1;
    for(;x>0;x-=50)
        acc+=to20(x);
    return acc;
}

int to100(x)
{
    int acc=1;
    for(;x>0;x-=100)
        acc+=to50(x);
    return acc;
}

int main()
{
    int test = to100(200)+1;
    printf("%d",test);
    return 0;
}
```

But the code gives 73685, not 73682 but I don't know why, could someone help me plz?

Comment: And what should it compute? The question should make sense on its own, not just after looking at assignments from other sites.

Comment: If at all appropriate, not everybody knows project Euler 31. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you initialize `acc` to 1? (It makes sense when `x` is a multiple of the number of the function, but only then.) change it to 0, and change the loop condition to `x>=0`. (If I understood your code).

Comment: @chubakueno Be sure to mark the [answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not need C code to solve, it is a problem of set selections. You need to solve `number of ways to select n coins where n > 0 and sum = 2£`, you should look up [Set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).
This should help you find a linear equation to compute the number.

Comment: Even better than Set theory, look for [Enumerative Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration) and [Generating Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)